# Accessing SOAP services with Google Apps Script

Tags: soap, google-apps-script

I'm trying to use Google Apps Scripts to call a SOAP service call, and I've been trying to tinker with a number of ways to get a response; however, I keep getting an error.  I've defaulted to trying to send an exact copy of a message stored in my spreadsheet that I know works through another service... still no luck.  Here's the Apps Script Code:

```
function getVesselSummaryXMLStringFromName() {
  var wsdl = SoapService.wsdl("http://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx?WSDL");
  Logger.log(wsdl.getServiceNames());

  var uscgService = wsdl.getPSIXData();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //Get working SOAP message
  var envelope = sheet.getRange("D1:D1").getValues();

  Logger.log(envelope);

    var result = uscgService.getenvelope;
    Logger.log(result);
  }
```

The SOAP message I'm sending that works through http://www.soapclient.com/soapclient is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://cgmix.uscg.mil" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ><SOAP-ENV:Body><tns:getVesselSummaryXMLString xmlns:tns="http://cgmix.uscg.mil"><tns:VesselID></tns:VesselID><tns:VesselID></tns:VesselID><tns:VesselName>Atlantic Salvor</tns:VesselName><tns:VesselName></tns:VesselName><tns:CallSign></tns:CallSign><tns:CallSign></tns:CallSign><tns:VIN></tns:VIN><tns:VIN></tns:VIN><tns:HullNum></tns:HullNum><tns:HullNum></tns:HullNum><tns:Flag></tns:Flag><tns:Flag></tns:Flag><tns:Service></tns:Service><tns:Service></tns:Service><tns:BuildYear></tns:BuildYear><tns:BuildYear></tns:BuildYear></tns:getVesselSummaryXMLString></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: The first comment that the [Soap Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/soap/) is a feature considered [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset). What error is generated?

Comment: Thanks for the response, appreciate the heads up it's on the sunset schedule.  It's not returning an error (though the method from the Google tutorial was).  The result is logged as undefined.  I submit the same envelope through another service, and I get the desired response.

Answer (score 1):

The following code returns an answer, so maybe you can help.

```
...
var url = 'http://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx?WSDL';
var wsdl = SoapService.wsdl(url);
var servicePSIXData = wsdl.getPSIXData();
var params = Xml.element('getVesselSummaryXMLString', [
    Xml.attribute('xmlns', 'http://cgmix.uscg.mil'),
    Xml.element('VesselID', ['']),
    Xml.element('VesselName', ['Atlantic Salvor']),
    Xml.element('CallSign', ['']),
    Xml.element('VIN', ['']),
    Xml.element('HullNum', ['']),
    Xml.element('Flag', ['']),
    Xml.element('Service', ['']),
    Xml.element('BuildYear', [''])
]);
var result = servicePSIXData.getVesselSummaryXMLString(params);
Logger.log(result.toXmlString());
...
```

**UPDATE**

Both [Xml Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml/) and [Soap Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/soap/) are considered [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset).

Comment: Thanks William.  Works for me.  Now I can go back and see what I was missing.